# Laravel, changing form fields based on category selection

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I have 2 categories in my db named 'House Rental' and 'Vehicle rental'

Users can post free ads based on the two categories.

My Listing model contains this:

```
 Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->id();
         $table->string('title');
         $table->text('body');
         $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
         $table->unsignedBigInteger('area_id');
         $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
         $table->boolean('live')->default(false);
         $table->softDeletes();
         $table->timestamps();
         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
         $table->foreign('area_id')->references('id')->on('areas')->onDelete('cascade');
         $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');


        });
```

When a user visits add listing form, say he selects 'House Rentals' category, I want the add form to show fields like 'size', 'rooms', 'building_type', 'is_furnished', 'is_parking', etc.

At the same time if a user adds a listing and he selects 'Vehicle Rentals', I want the add form to show fields like  'vehicle_model', 'year_of_registration', 'condition', etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: are you using jquery or vuejs for frontend?

Comment: vuejs for the frontend

Comment: Then you should implement this logic on frontend. You can show or hide a form according to the type you select.

Comment: What about the backend? do i need another table or so?

Comment: You can create a Bootstrap tab items with 2 forms - one to create House Rental another to create a Vehicle rental

Comment: it depends on your database table structure that how you want to save your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a single `vue` component that can be of assistance

```
<template>
  <div> 
     <form @submit.prevent="iEdit ? iUpdate(): createMethod()">
        <label> Select Rental </label>
        <select class="form-control" @change="rentalChanged($event)" v-model="rentalForm.rental_category"> 
           <option value="house rental"> House Rental </option>
           <option value="vehicle rental"> Vehicle Rental </option>
        </select>

        <select v-if="house_rental">
           <!-- show house rental options -->
        </select>

        <select v-if="vehicle_rental">
           <!-- show vencle rental options -->
        </select>

     </form>
  </div>
</template>


<script> 
    name: 'componentName',

    data(){

      return {
          rentalForm: new Form({
             rental_category: '',
             another_form_field:'',
          }),
          iEdit : false,
          vehicle_rental :false,
          house_rental: false,
      }

    },

    methods{
        rentalChanged(event){

            if(event.target.value == 'house rental'){
               this.house_rental = true;
               this.vehicle_rental = false;
            }

            if(event.target.value == 'vehicle rental'){
               this.house_rental = false;
               this.vehicle_rental = true;
            }
        },

        iUpdate(){
          //update method
        },

        createMethod(){
          //create method
        },

    },

    mounted(){
    }
</script>
```

I hope it gives a clue I didn't test it.